# spring integration jdbc lock registry - delete from INT_LOCK query has timed out

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch, mssql-jdbc

I'm using Spring integration 4.3.14, Spring batch 3.8.0 and mssql driver 6.1.0.

I have multiple process running in parallel (2 pods) and all goes to aggregator backed with jdbc message store and lock registry.

For this job, each pods are limited to use 8 threads at max. For smaller data it is fine, but when the data is big and all threads are busy in doing DB operations, I'm are getting query timeout exception for INT_LOCK table's delete query.

Query timeout is not set for the DB connection. Other long queries are running without timeout.

Once the error occurs, the message goes to errorChannel and the job is failed.

Please help me on this.

**Error message payload:**

`org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.config.AggregatorFactoryBean#0]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Failed to lock mutex at f53339e4-9017-3231-821d-5a6d11144496; 
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [DELETE FROM INT_LOCK WHERE REGION=? AND LOCK_KEY=? AND CREATED_DATE<?]; SQL
state [HY008]; error code [0]; The query has timed out.; 
nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query has timed out.`

Comment: Please, be sure that you use transactions around that Aggregator

Comment: Do we have any documentation on using Aggregator with transaction? I was trying to find out [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#aggregator-config)

Comment: This should help a bit: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#message-handler-advice-chain. You need a `tx:advice` configuration there